# Reporting yielded results of long-running Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

#### Problem

I've segmented a long-running task into logical subtasks, so I can report the results of each subtask as it completes. However, I'm trying to report the results of a task that will effectively never complete (instead yielding values as it goes), and am struggling to do so with my existing solution.

#### Background

I'm building a web interface to some Python programs I've written. Users can submit jobs through web forms, then check back to see the job's progress.

Let's say I have two functions, each accessed via separate forms:

- `med_func`: Takes ~1 minute to execute, results are passed off to `render()`, which produces additional data.
- `long_func`: Returns a generator. Each `yield` takes on the order of 30 minutes, and should be reported to the user. There are so many yields, we can consider this iterator as infinite (terminating only when [revoked](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html?highlight=revoke#celery.app.control.Control.revoke)).

#### Code, current implementation

With `med_func`, I report results as follows:

On form submission, I save an `AsyncResult` to a [Django session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#):

```
    task_result = med_func.apply_async([form], link=render.s())
    request.session["task_result"] = task_result
```

The Django view for the results page accesses this `AsyncResult`. When a task has completed, results are saved into an object that is passed as context to a Django template.

```
def results(request):
    """ Serve (possibly incomplete) results of a session's latest run. """
    session = request.session

    try:  # Load most recent task
        task_result = session["task_result"]
    except KeyError:  # Already cleared, or doesn't exist
        if "results" not in session:
            session["status"] = "No job submitted"
    else:  # Extract data from Asynchronous Tasks
        session["status"] = task_result.status
        if task_result.ready():
            session["results"] = task_result.get()
            render_task = task_result.children[0]

            # Decorate with rendering results
            session["render_status"] = render_task.status
            if render_task.ready():
                session["results"].render_output = render_task.get()
                del(request.session["task_result"])  # Don't need any more

    return render_to_response('results.html', request.session)
```

This solution only works when the function actually *terminates*. I can't chain together logical subtasks of `long_func`, because there are an unknown number of `yield`s (each iteration of `long_func`'s loop may not produce a result).

#### Question

Is there any sensible way to access yielded objects from an extremely long-running Celery task, so that they can be displayed before the generator is exhausted?

Comment: This question is vague and the comments ask a different question altogether.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate more on the actual question "Is there any sensible way to render yielded objects from an extremely long-running Celery task?"? With 'render' you mean you want to somehow be able to get the results of not ending task in a view function? How do these results look like (model instances?)?

Comment: Fair points, @Brent and @Bernhard; what I'm going for here isn't actually _rendering_ the results, per se, but rather being able to access yielded values before the generator completes (so that they can be rendered on the page). So, yes, I'm essentially trying to display as much as possible about a task's progress, within a view function, before the task terminates.

Comment: And @Bernhard, the "results" are just standard Python objects, completely separate from Celery and Django (I could use the program as a standalone Python application).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order for Celery to know what the current state of the task is, it sets some metadata in whatever result backend you have.  You can piggy-back on that to store other kinds of metadata.

```
def yielder():
    for i in range(2**100):
        yield i

@task
def report_progress():
    for progress in yielder():
        # set current progress on the task
        report_progress.backend.mark_as_started(
            report_progress.request.id,
            progress=progress)

def view_function(request):
    task_id = request.session['task_id']
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)
    progress = task.info['progress']
    # do something with your current progress
```

I wouldn't throw a *ton* of data in there, but it works well for tracking the progress of a long-running task.

Comment: I get the following error: `celery.backends.amqp.BacklogLimitExceeded: 483bb075-a27c-4298-8227-3bbebb13074f`. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 15):

Paul's answer is great. As an alternative to using `mark_as_started` you can use `Task`'s `update_state` method. They ultimately do the same thing, but the name "update_state" is a little more appropriate for what you're trying to do. You can optionally define a [custom state](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) that indicates your task is in progress (I've named my custom state 'PROGRESS'):

```
def yielder():
    for i in range(2**100):
        yield i

@task
def report_progress():
    for progress in yielder():
        # set current progress on the task
        report_progress.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'progress': progress})

def view_function(request):
    task_id = request.session['task_id']
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)
    progress = task.info['progress']
    # do something with your current progress
```

Answer (score 6):

Celery part:

```
def long_func(*args, **kwargs):
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        do_something_here(*args, **kwargs)
        i += 1


@task()
def test_yield_task(task_id=None, **kwargs):
    the_progress = 0        
    for the_progress in long_func(**kwargs):
        cache.set('celery-task-%s' % task_id, the_progress)
```

Webclient side, starting task:

```
r = test_yield_task.apply_async()
request.session['task_id'] = r.task_id
```

Testing last yielded value:

```
   v = cache.get('celery-task-%s' % session.get('task_id'))
   if v:
        do_someting()
```

If you do not like to use cache, or it's impossible, you can use db, file or any other place which celery worker and server side will have both accesss. With cache it's a simplest solution, but workers and server have to use the same cache.

Answer (score 4):

A couple options to consider:

1 -- task groups.  If you can enumerate all the sub tasks from the time of invocation, you can apply the group as a whole -- that returns a TaskSetResult object you can use to monitor the results of the group as a whole, or of individual tasks in the group -- query this as-needed when you need to check status.

2 -- callbacks.  If you can't enumerate all sub tasks (or even if you can!) you can define a web hook / callback that's the last step in the task -- called when the rest of the task completes. The hook would be against a URI in your app that ingests the result and makes it available via DB or app-internal API.

Some combination of these could solve your challenge.

Answer (score 3):

See also this great PyCon preso from one of the Instagram engineers.

http://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/04/how-instagram-feeds-work-celery-and-rabbitmq.html

At video mark 16:00, he discusses how they structure long lists of sub-tasks.