# How to make a 'please wait' page in the mean time of long process of a function in django

Tags: python, django

In my view.py file, there is a url(function). There is a function which is dumping a big data to database, which takes minimum 5 min to take completion.

So I need to show a "Please Wait" page to user and then redirect to next page. I can think a solution is to make two url.

Like """ dump_permission ->please_wait(here that dumping may occur)-> after_completation_fun """. I don't have idea about celery or ajax.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052291/reporting-yielded-results-of-long-running-celery-task