# Django: Real-time logging to browser

Tags: django, echo, real-time

In PHP, I used to be able to use the `echo` command and see scripts in real time.

For example:

```
Applying settings to 001...
* a second later *
Applying settings to 002...
```

This would be shown to the user in the browser.
Is there anyways I can use a command like echo in Django?
It's nice to know my application is actually doing something and seeing the progress.

Comment: Have you tried `print`?

Comment: With all due respect, I'd like to suggest to familiarize yourself with [Python basics](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Hello%2C_World!), then checkout [Django's logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/)

Comment: I understand print can be used, but that's only for the console. I'd like to have a real time information printed out and returned to the user through their browser, like I was able to accomplish with PHP.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this, and a cursory google search came back with no canned modules. Basically, I hear you asking for logging over an http streaming response from Django, so you have my thoughts for search terms. Is there a reason why you specifically need this functionality? Could it be acceptable to use something else, such as file-based logging, and monitor the log file for changes? (`tail -f logfile`)

Comment: Alternatively, if you need log messages for *this request* and are okay with operating with `DEBUG = True`, you can use the `django-debug-toolbar` to view all log messages generated when servicing the current response. But it's not real-time.

Comment: Django caches all responses before sending them to the browser, if you want to stream content while you're generating them, use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse). But for debugging, it's better to use proper logging and Django Debug Toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's nice to know my application is actually doing something and seeing the progress.

I'm assuming you want to inform an actual user of the progress of some long running task, and not merely print debugging statements. As for debugging or code tracing, use Django's [logging subsystem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/) in combination with [django-debugtoolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

> Is there anyways I can use a command like echo in Django?

Since Django 1.5, there is a [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) that kind of allows you to emulate php's `echo` behavior, under some circumstances.

However, take into account what it says in the Documentation:

> Django is designed for short-lived requests. Streaming responses will tie a worker process for the entire duration of the response. This may result in poor performance.

That said, there is an [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-csv-files).

**Really?**

Note that the *recommended and stable way* of doing this, in any HTTP request/response driven context (which Django is designed for), is to use an asynchronous task processor like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for any long-lived processes. Then use a polling client to check on the progress, e.g. as proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17203290/890242).